# $\chi^2$ test and sparsely populated bins

Tags: chi-squared-test, references

Which article should I reference as a source of the following claim?:

*The $\chi^2$ test is not recommended when too many sparsely populated bins exist in a given histogram.*

Please rephrase the above sentence if it is not clear.

[This article](http://goo.gl/GVlSO) (page 328) by W. Cochran states something along that lines, but it's pretty old (1952) and it's not at all conclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a screen capture of the first half of the relevant page from Bhattacharya and Johnson, [Statistical Concepts and Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471072044), in response to a request in comments to @gung's answer:

[image: Page 435]

Answer (score 3):

The recommendation that all the expected values meet or exceed 5 for a chi-squared test is very old and very well-known.  You may not have to substantiate it with a citation.  It is also somewhat arbitrary, and this is also pretty well known.  There won't be a 'bright line' anywhere separating conditions under which the test works just fine vs. breaks down--there can't be.  Again, any research statistician will know this or immediately intuit it.  As a result, I doubt there will be much research substantiating the 5 rule of thumb.  If you wanted to cite something anyway, the Cochran paper may be sufficient.

If you want to pursue this for your own edification, you may want to read [Campbell (2007)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.2832/abstract) and the various papers that cite it.  This is not quite the same context as yours, but the underlying issue is the same.

Comment: +1. If one wants a citation for this, it would probably be found most readily in a introductory textbook intended for non-statisticians.

Comment: I think Macro is right.  The rule is probably mentioned in many introductory books.  You might also look at van Belle's "Statistical Rules of Thumb" book.  I know I have seen it many times and I think it goes back to results of Cochran from before the 1952 survey paper that was found.  I don't know if Cochran made the recommendation directly or someone else did based on his results.  But this may be difficult to track down.  Books on the history of statistics might say something about this and statistics encyclopedias under the chj square test item or even in a biography of Cochran.

Comment: Statistical Concepts and Methods, Bhattacharya and Johnson, p. 425.  On Amazon for $171.50 despite the 1977 publication date!!! http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Concepts-Methods-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471072044#reader_0471072044

Comment: @jbowman could you put your comment in the form of an answer and if you can, copy/paste the lines(s) in that book that address the issue? I don't have access to that book and I can't pay $172 for one single reference. Thanks!

Comment: Gaba_p you can see it yourself using the LOOK INSIDE feature on Amazon, jbowman's link will take you there. It's on p.425 as he says. It merely states "As a rule of thumb, $n$ should be large enough so that the expected frequency of each cell is at least 5". It does not cite a paper to substantiate this there or anywhere else that I see. Similar statements of the rule of thumb exist in most intro texts as Macro notes. You could simply cite that book, I think that is what he meant, not that you should buy it.

Comment: Right, I was just expressing surprise about the price.  LOOK INSIDE will take you there.  If you can't get there for some reason, and really want to see the page for yourself (quite reasonable if you're going to cite it!) I'll post a screenshot of the top half of the page, where the quote that @gung cites is.

Comment: I did try the _Look Inside_ feature but it will only let me see up to page 6, after that it jumps to the index (this might be due to the fact that I'm accessing from outside the US) A screenshot would be great @jbowman, the quote by gung is fine but I'd really like to see the text if it's not too much trouble for you.

Comment: Try looking at the table of contents, then scroll down to the entry for page 424, click on it, and that should take you to the page before; then you can scroll to page 425.  I don't know about outside the U.S., though, so I'll post the screenshot too.

Comment: Nope, if I do that it takes me to the end of the book.